# Lebesgue measure of set of spheres with irrational radii

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For each $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ Let $$ S_{\alpha} =\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3/x^2+y^2+z^2=\alpha^2 \}$$
Let $E=\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb R\vert \mathbb Q} S_\alpha$. Which of the following options are true?

1. The lebesgue measure of $E$ is infinite
2. $E$  contains a non-empty open set
3. $E$  is path connected
4. Every open set containing $E^c$ has infinite Lebesgue measure.

I think options 1 and 4 are true. Because Lebesgue measure of irrationals in $ \mathbb R$ is infinite. For option 2, if $E$ contain non empty open set than it would intersect some point of sphere with rational radius. I am confused about options 3 and 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1.$ is true because $\mu(E^c)=0$ since it's a countable sum of sets that are measure zero.

$2. $ is obviously false.

$ 3. $ is false, because you can't connect points lying on a different circle

$4.$ is also false, because $\mu(E^c)=0$

Comment: Why 4 is false? Here we are considering OPEN SET containing $E^c$

Comment: @ramanujan Since $\mu(E^c)=0$, from the regularity of Lebesgue measure we can find an open set $A$ such that $\mu(A)\leq\mu(E^c)+\varepsilon$ and  $E^c \subset A$. So we can find an open set so that for example $\mu(A)=1$ and $A \subset E^c$

Comment: I meant $\mu(A)=1$ and $E^c \subset A$